# Java for loop I want to print the result the same way that i print the numbers that i use

Tags: java, for-loop, pow

I want to print the result the same way that i print the numbers that i use.
for ex i print 1,2,3,4  2,3,4,5 but the pow remains the same 1024,1024,1024,1024.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int d = 0, e = 0;
    double c = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < 5; a++) {
        d = a;
        for (int b = 2; b < 6; b++) {
            c = java.lang.Math.pow(a, b);
        }
    }
    for (int a = 1, b = 2; a < 5; a++, b++) {
        d = a;
        e = b;
        System.out.println(d + " " + e + " " + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: first please make the effort to format your code properly. this would better illustrate your problem.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
   int d=0 ,e= 0;
   double c = 0;
   for (int a=1;a<5;a++) 
   { 
    d=a;
    for (int b=2;b<6;b++) { 
    
     c=java.lang.Math.pow (a,b);
    
    }
   
    }
  
   for (int a=1,b=2;a<5;a++,b++) {
    d=a;
       
 
     e=b;
    
    System.out.println ( d+ " " +e +" " + c); 
    }
 }
 
 }

Comment: @Koon This is worse.

Comment: @luckydog32 The problem is that  i cant print all the pow it print only the last part .

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stackoverflow. This questio is quite low-quality and probably your first question here and will most probably be closed soon. To prevent this from happening again in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read what is regraded as on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [the information about how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Turing85 you are right but i thought that people here would resolve this blinded

Comment: @Koon so... you thought you could use other to do you (home)work for free? Nice attittude...

Comment: @Turing85 thnx for the editing,it is not a homework it is a way to understand printing of the for loop.

Comment: @Koon No one on here is going to be able to fix a problem if they don't know what it is. There's plenty of people on here that will be able to help you out with a programming question, as long as there is at least an effort to explain what the question is.

Comment: @luckydog32  I want to find the power of a and b  a starts from 1 till 4 b form 2 till 5  and i want to show the power of a and b like this
1    2    1 ,  
  
2    3    8 ,  
  
3    4    81,4 5 1024 but my program shows a and b and 1024 only not 1,8,81,1024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, and is also more readable.(you really ought to indent code properly).
Your problem is in the loop logic.
What you are doing is probably possible with `for` loops, but i think a `while` loop with two conditionals would work nice.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
double c = 0.0;

while (a < 5 && b < 6){
  c=java.lang.Math.pow (a,b);
  System.out.println ( a+ " " +b +" " + c); 
  b++;
  a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int d = 0, e = 0;
    double c = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < 5; a++) {
        for (int b = 2; b < 6; b++) {

            c = java.lang.Math.pow(a, b);
            System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);

        }

    }
}
```

If I understood your problem try something like this output should be ok